# Java: How to make multiple HTTPS request with only one SSL handshake?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I'm looking to keep a persistent HTTPS connections between two services. I would like to have a single dedicated SSL connection for transmitting all messages. I'm currently seeing seeing that each HTTPS request triggers a new handshake, albeit it's a session resume. How can I keep the SSL session alive between multiple HTTP requests? I'm using standard HttpsUrlConnection.

Comment: This needs an short self-contained, correct example (http://sscce.org/) or at the very minimum a description of the libraries being used for making the HTTP requests.

Comment: @Dev It doesn't really. The features he is looking for are an automatic part of any SSL library.

Comment: @EJP I assumed he was having issues with making HTTP persistent connections work correctly. It is difficult to give a specific answer without knowing how HTTP is being handled in his code.

Comment: @Dev His question is about SSL handshakes and 'keep[ing] the SSL session alive between multiple HTTP requests', which already happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm currently seeing seeing that each HTTPS request triggers a new handshake, albeit it's a session resume. How can I keep the SSL session alive between multiple HTTP requests?

The fact that it's a session resume indicates that what you are asking for is already happening. The new connection is joining an existing SSL session.

When you put HTTP keep-alive on top of that, whereby TCP connections are reused for multiple requests, with no re-handshake at all, there is really nothing left of your requirement that isn't already there.

Your question doesn't make sense, or is already answered by the existing implementation.